# How to include Reason of build failure in Jenkins in Email-Ext plugin

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am using Email-Ext plugin to send Email .
I am able to fetch many of details like build status nunit results change sets using jelly script but I am not able to get the reason for failure of build for example "abc command is not recognized as internal command" How should i include the exact reason of build failure in email message

Comment: Are you trying to create a customized email content having specific details only? If not, you can always send the entire console log as email text. The console log would also have the error details

Comment: I dont want to send entire console just want to send only error reason

Answer (score 1):

You can edit the jelly script to send particular error.
Here's how I did it for jUnit tests. nunit should be something similar
http://habibbabbles.blogspot.com/2013/09/how-to-show-stacktrace-standard-output.html